# Implementing ASP.NET MVC 3 Interface Model Binding (with ViewModel)

Tags: .net, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, model-binding

I just learning ASP.NET MVC 3 and I'm a bit confused on how I can implement something like what is shown in this link:

http://www.codethinked.com/easy-and-safe-model-binding-in-aspnet-mvc

Why I'm confused is most likely based on my ignorance in the subject.  In the example on the page linked above, I see Justin is using a ViewModel that directly contains properties of his "Person" object.

What I want to do is similar, but I want to have a ViewModel actually contain the domain class, which is in my case Company, rather than Person.  I'm having the Company class itself implement the ViewModel subset views (ex. IEditCompanyAsUser).

What I've tried so far looks something like so:

```
public class Company : IValidatableObject, ICompanyUpdateAsUser
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Boolean Active { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }

    // Containing some more members below
 }
```

With ICompanyUpdateAsUser containing the properties I would like my controller's Edit method to update:

```
public interface ICompanyUpdateAsUser
{
    bool Active { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Phone { get; set; }  
}
```

And a ViewModel class that looks like so:

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
    public Company Company;
    // Will be adding more members in the future
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to properly code the controller.  My controller currently looks like so:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: /Company/Edit/5
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix="Company")]Company model)
    {
        var company = _companyService.GetCompany(model.CompanyID);

        if (company == null)
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (TryUpdateModel<ICompanyUpdateAsUser>(company))
            {
                _companyService.SaveCompany();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { companyId = model.CompanyID });
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

I know something is absolutely wrong with my controller code but I can't figure out what components I need to use to implement such a pattern?  Do I need to use a custom model binder?  Do I need to use some other feature of ASP.NET MVC3 to implement the pattern?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

****EDIT****

What I need to do is have the Edit view post back a "Company" object, then update the object from the database with the values on the post'ed Company (according to the properties on the interface passed to TryUpdateModel).  Everything appears to be working (validation, etc.), but the TryUpdateModel(company) does not seem to be working, though evaluating to true.  When I step through the code with a debugger, the Company object pulled from the DB is simply never updated.

After a bit more reading, I've determined the TryUpdateModel method updates the passed item from the method's IValueProvider.  How can I associated the passed in "Company model" with the IValueProvider for the method?

Comment: In your code it seems you are trying to achieve more than what the article is targeting.  Can you be specific about what is the behavior you are expecting from your code, and also how is it behaving now?  That would help us arrive at a focused answer.

Comment: Yes, what I'm trying to do is pass a ViewModel containing the Company and maybe some other data to the View, and from the View post the company back to the Edit method in the controller.  From here, I want to validate the Company object passed in & update it in the database.  Does that make sense or do I need to elaborate more?

Comment: @slashp.  Also, you mentioned it isn't working.  Could you describe what is happening when you a run the code,  is there an error?

Comment: No error, just doesn't do...anything..at all.

Comment: When running through the application in a debugger, the model state is always valid no matter what, then nothing happens in the database.

Comment: Turns out there is an error if I try to submit an invalid form (only after decorating the interface with validation attributes): The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Project.Models.Domain.Company', but this dictionary requires a model of type 'Project.Models.ViewModels.CompanyViewModels.CompanyEditViewModel'

Comment: Curious ... is the if (TryUpdateModel<ICompanyUpdateAsUser>(company)) evaluating to true?

Comment: Yes, the TryUpdateModel<ICompanyUpdateAsUser>(company) is in fact evaluating to true.

Comment: The comments are getting too long.  Might makes sense to add your debugging details to your question.  Will respond in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up resolving the issue by first making a couple of modifications..in my question, my controller failed to use the ViewModel class I had created.  Once I modified the controller to look like so:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// POST: /Company/Edit/5
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(CompanyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var company = _companyService.GetCompany(viewModel.Company.CompanyID);

        if (company == null)
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (TryUpdateModel<ICompanyUpdateAsUser>(company, "Company"))
            {
                _companyService.SaveCompany();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { companyId = viewModel.Company.CompanyID });
            }
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I found that everything appeared to be working properly, but as stated in the comments above TryUpdateModel simply DID NOT work, though returning true!

After sifting through tons of Stack Overflow & other forum posts, I eventually found that TryUpdateModel does not work on fields, only properties.  To get it working properly I had to modify my ViewModel to look like so:

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public CompanyViewModel(Company company)
    {
        Company = company;
    }

    public CompanyViewModel()
    {
        Company = new Company();
    }
 }
```

Such a silly mistake, though I feel this point is far overlooked by many of the model binding tutorials I have read.

Hopefully this answer will save someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an overload of TryUpdateModel that takes in a prefix. Since it sounds like your original view model contained your Company object, then the name of the form fields that were generated for the Company object (assuming you're using standard form input names), contain a prefix of "Company", it looks like you've recognized this with the model that the method is taking in, try using the same prefix when updating your domain object.

FYI, it's generally not best practice to use your domain objects in your view model, the main reason for this is that there could be fields you don't want to allow a user to update. If a user has enough knowledge about your domain, they can add additional form fields into the post data, and MVC would blindly update those property/fields and that could cause a problem. There are ways of telling MVC to exclude certain properties/fields when binding, but it becomes a maintenance nightmare and is usually easier to use separate objects for your views.

Comment: I understand the problem with the possibility of a malicious user adding additional form fields & posting to fields that should not be modified--this is the whole reason I'm trying to use the TryUpdateModel<IUpdateCompanyAsUser> with the interface containing only the properties I'd like to update.  Am I doing something completely wrong to implement such a pattern?

Comment: OK, I glossed over the fact that you explicitly defined the type for TryUpdateModel. I'd like to think that would work, but I haven't done it before. Did you try setting the prefix to that method to see if the form data was bound to it correctly?

Comment: Yep, tried that too.  I eventually got it working, thanks for the help, though!

Comment: Glad you got it working, care to post your solution in case someone else has a similar problem in the future?